# Linux system call for creating process and thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, system-calls

I read in a [paper](http://www.cs.umass.edu/~emery/pubs/fs-oopsla2011.pdf) that the underlying system call to create processes and threads is actually the same, and thus the cost of creating processes over threads is not that great.

- First, I wanna know what is the system call that creates
  processes/threads (possibly a sample code or a link?)
- Second, is
  the author correct to assume that creating processes instead of
  threads is inexpensive?

**EDIT:**
Quoting article:

> Replacing pthreads with processes is surprisingly inexpensive,
>   especially on Linux where both pthreads and processes are invoked
>   using the same underlying system call.

Comment: creating processes *instead* of threads?  No.  In general, threads are lightweight processes. However, the line is somewhat blurred because of things like copy on write.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Processes are usually created with `fork`, threads (lightweight processes) are usually created with `clone` nowadays. However, anecdotically, there exist 1:N thread models, too, which don't do either.

Both `fork` and `clone` map to the same kernel function `do_fork` internally. This function can create a lightweight process that shares the address space with the old one, or a separate process (and many other options), depending on what flags you feed to it. The `clone` syscall is more or less a direct forwarding of that kernel function (and used by the higher level threading libraries) whereas `fork` wraps `do_fork` into the functionality of the 50 year old traditional Unix function.

The important difference is that `fork` guarantees that a complete, separate copy of the address space is made. This, as Basil points out correctly, is done with copy-on-write nowadays and therefore is not nearly as expensive as one would think.
When you create a thread, it just reuses the original address space and the same memory.

However, one should not assume that creating processes is generally "lightweight" on unix-like systems because of copy-on-write. It is somewhat less heavy than for example under Windows, but it's nowhere near free.
One reason is that although the actual pages are not copied, the new process still needs a copy of the page table. This can be several kilobytes to megabytes of memory for processes that use larger amounts of memory.
Another reason is that although copy-on-write is invisible and a clever optimization, it is not free, and it cannot do magic. When data is modified by either process, which inevitably happens, the affected pages fault.

Redis is a good example where you can see that `fork` is everything but lightweight (it uses `fork` to do background saves).

Comment: Thank you. I searched for do_fork, I found it's source. Are there any documentations on how to use it?

Comment: Unless you write kernel code, you won't directly call `do_fork` at all. You probably don't want to use `clone` in general either (it's recommended to use the pthreads library built on top of it instead). Anyway, in case you _do want_ to use `clone`, the documentation is [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clone.2.html). Now `fork` on the other hand, is something you may realistically want to use, the docs are [on the same site](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html).

Comment: I'm doing a review on this paper, I want to know how things actually work. I found the source code for `fork` and  `pthread_create`. But I can't find any calls to `do_fork`.

Comment: Unluckily Google Code Search has shut down, and Koders is an ordeal to work with... Here are [some implementations](http://www.koders.com/c/fid82DECC76F2D7933450BC7DD2B52895F236E9B139.aspx?s=sys_clone#L177) (there are different ones in different arch subfolders, but probably not much different, if at all) for both sys_fork and sys_clone that I could find with a quick search.

Answer (score 6):

The underlying system call to create threads is [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) (it is Linux specific). BTW, the list of Linux system calls is on [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), and you could use the [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) command to understand the syscalls done by some process or command. Processes are usually created with [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (or [vfork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html), which is not much useful these days). However, you could (and some C standard libraries might do that) create them with some particular form of `clone`. I guess that the kernel is sharing some code to implement `clone`, `fork` etc... (since some functionalities, e.g. management of the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), are common).

Indeed, process creation (and also thread creation) is generally quite fast on most Unix systems (because they use [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) machinery for the [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)), typically a small fraction of a millisecond. But you could have pathological cases (e.g. [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science))) which makes that much longer.

Since most [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementations are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) on Linux, you could study the source code of the one on your system (often [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), but sometimes [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or something else).

Comment: So they're different system calls?

Comment: They are different, but AFAIU `fork` could be implemented with `clone` (but predated it by dozen of years).